# Send complete TCP or UDP packs programmatically

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, udp, network-protocols

According to OSI Model, data packets will be completed in several layers.
Is it possible to send **complete TCP or UDP packets** (including headers and etc) **programmatically**.

For example a packet whit custom MAC ADD. and a fake IP for sender (requester)?

Comment: complete TCP/UDP packets should not manipulate L2 or L3, those are on a lower layer. TCP/UDP packets are payload of L2/L3. But in short: yes you can do this. As for how: ask a decent question (which programming language, what have you tried, what do you want to accomplish with this, ...?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
You can put any TCP or UDP packet header if you are sending it using RAW sockets , for which you must have a **root** access to the system:

```
sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

Or you can also bypass linux TCP stack and write() and read() with the ethernet card directly.

The problem is, if you use fake ip with TCP, you won't get a response from SYN request because the real ip will reject it or it simply won't be routed back. You can research on this if you query for "ip spoofing" keywords.